# how to do a conditional map from two dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have following 2 data frames in pandas

```
df1

date         tank        quantity
2018-04-01   1           234
2018-04-02   1           343
2018-04-03   1           334
2018-04-04   1           143
2018-04-05   1           237
2018-04-06   1           234
2018-04-07   1           last observation
2018-04-01   2           234
2018-04-02   2           343
2018-04-03   2           334
2018-04-04   2           143
2018-04-05   2           237
2018-04-06   2           234
2018-04-07   2           last observation

df2
date         tank        quantity
2018-04-01   1           221
2018-04-02   1           200
2018-04-03   1           100
2018-04-04   1           123
2018-04-05   1           234.56
2018-04-06   1           324.67
2018-04-07   1           324.67
2018-04-01   2           221
2018-04-02   2           221.23 
2018-04-03   2           222.21
2018-04-04   2           453
2018-04-05   2           443
2018-04-06   2           234
2018-04-07   2           456
```

My desired dataframe would look like

```
 df1

 date         tank        quantity
 2018-04-01   1           234
 2018-04-02   1           343
 2018-04-03   1           334
 2018-04-04   1           143
 2018-04-05   1           237
 2018-04-06   1           234
 2018-04-07   1           324.67
 2018-04-01   2           234
 2018-04-02   2           343
 2018-04-03   2           334
 2018-04-04   2           143
 2018-04-05   2           237
 2018-04-06   2           234
 2018-04-07   2           456
```

I want to only replace values from df2 where quantity column value is `last observation` in df1.

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are same `date`s and `tank` values, and same index in both `DataFrames`:

```
df1.loc[df1['quantity'].eq('last observation'), 'quantity'] = df2['quantity']
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'].astype(float)
print (df1)
          date  tank  quantity
0   2018-04-01     1    234.00
1   2018-04-02     1    343.00
2   2018-04-03     1    334.00
3   2018-04-04     1    143.00
4   2018-04-05     1    237.00
5   2018-04-06     1    234.00
6   2018-04-07     1    324.67
7   2018-04-01     2    234.00
8   2018-04-02     2    343.00
9   2018-04-03     2    334.00
10  2018-04-04     2    143.00
11  2018-04-05     2    237.00
12  2018-04-06     2    234.00
13  2018-04-07     2    456.00
```

If not, use `merge` with left join first and then replace by new joined column:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date','tank'], how='left', suffixes=('_',''))

df1.loc[df1['quantity'].eq('last observation'), 'quantity'] = df['quantity']
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'].astype(float)
print (df1)
          date  tank  quantity
0   2018-04-01     1    234.00
1   2018-04-02     1    343.00
2   2018-04-03     1    334.00
3   2018-04-04     1    143.00
4   2018-04-05     1    237.00
5   2018-04-06     1    234.00
6   2018-04-07     1    324.67
7   2018-04-01     2    234.00
8   2018-04-02     2    343.00
9   2018-04-03     2    334.00
10  2018-04-04     2    143.00
11  2018-04-05     2    237.00
12  2018-04-06     2    234.00
13  2018-04-07     2    456.00
```

Comment: What if the no of observations are different in `df1` and `df2` ?

Comment: @Neil - Necesary first create `MultiIndex` and then apply solutions

Answer (score 5):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['quantity'] = np.where(df1['quantity'].eq('last observation'), df2['quantity'], 
                           df1['quantity']).astype(float)
```

Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'].mask(df1['quantity'].eq('last observation'), 
                                       df2['quantity']).astype(float)
```

Or [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where):

```
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'].where(df1['quantity'].ne('last observation'), 
                                        df2['quantity']).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) You should use `merge` first to join both frames on `date` and `tank` to find similar records:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date','tank'])
Out[505]: 
          date  tank        quantity_x  quantity_y
0   2018-04-01     1               234      221.00
1   2018-04-02     1               343      200.00
2   2018-04-03     1               334      100.00
3   2018-04-04     1               143      123.00
4   2018-04-05     1               237      234.56
5   2018-04-06     1               234      324.67
6   2018-04-07     1  last observation      324.67
7   2018-04-01     2               234      221.00
8   2018-04-02     2               343      221.23
9   2018-04-03     2               334      222.21
10  2018-04-04     2               143      453.00
11  2018-04-05     2               237      443.00
12  2018-04-06     2               234      234.00
13  2018-04-07     2  last observation      456.00
```

2.) Now use `np.where` to substitute the value of `last observation`

```
df['quantity_x'] = np.where(df['quantity_x']=='last observation', df['quantity_y'], df['quantity_x'])
df.drop('quantity_y', 1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['date','tank','quantity']

In [515]: df
Out[515]: 
          date  tank   quantity
0   2018-04-01     1        234
1   2018-04-02     1        343
2   2018-04-03     1        334
3   2018-04-04     1        143
4   2018-04-05     1        237
5   2018-04-06     1        234
6   2018-04-07     1     324.67
7   2018-04-01     2        234
8   2018-04-02     2        343
9   2018-04-03     2        334
10  2018-04-04     2        143
11  2018-04-05     2        237
12  2018-04-06     2        234
13  2018-04-07     2        456
```